# Git default URL issues

Tags: git, gitlab

Below I mention an error this while cloning the project.

**cloning project...
fatal: unable to access 'URL': Failed to connect to 192.168.0.141 port 1080: Timed out**

Am using windows 10 operating version.
And Internal using a gitlab account. But in my network this ip address and port {192.168.0.141 port 1080}
not available. It only take 192.168.0.141:1080..How to change this url

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have an HTTP(S)_PROXY set in your environment: type

```
set HTTP
```

If the result is not empty, that could be the IP address your clone https tries to reach.

In the case of an internal gitlab server at myGitLab.company.com, you need to set NO_PROXY first:

```
set NO_PROXY=.company.com,localhost
```

That way, your `git clone https://myGitLab.company.com/aUser/aRepo` will work.

Comment: ...didn't you mean to write `get HTTP` for the first snippet of code?

Comment: @RomainVALERI No: on Windows, in a CMD session, `set HTTP` will display any environment variable starting with HTTP.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the lightning-fast and useful answer. Take care

Comment: @VonC... Thanks for your replay. I  did this above comment but is not working. While cloning it showing the same error

Comment: @favasaman Yes, but first: did you had a proxy set? (as shown in the answer)